# Get unique List elements based on a substring

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList(String) which contains a list of formatted dates like this:

```
element 1: "2012-5-1"
element 2: "2012-8-10"
element 3: "2012-12-5"
element 4: "2013-12-21"
element 5: "2013-12-13"
element 6: "2014-5-8"
```

What is the most efficient/framework way to create another list or normal primitive array that contains the unique year entries? For example my new list would contain:

```
element 1: "2012"
element 2: "2013"
element 3: "2014"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
ArrayList<String> yearsOnlylist = new ArrayList<String> ();
for(String s : elements) {
    String yearExtracted = s.substring(0,4);
    yearsOnlylist.add(yearExtracted);
}
```

Where *elements* is the name of your list of date in the extended form.

Using as destination list

```
 LinkedList<String> yearsOnlylist = new LinkedList<String> ();
```

instead of an *ArrayList* could sightly improve the conversion efficiency (because the add is *O(1)* in LinkedList) but access a specific position in a second time, has a lower efficiency (*O(n)* vs *O(1)*).

Answer (score 2):

Just add them to a Set and convert it to a list:

```
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>();
for (String element : elements) {
    set.put(element.substring(0,4));
}
List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>();
uniqueList.addAll(unique);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through your array list and take a substring of the first 4 characters of each member of the array list.

Add that substring to a set implementation such as a HashSet, which will give you what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
public List<String> trimmer(List<String> x) {
    Log.e("", Integer.toString(x.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        String s = x.get(i).toString(); 
        String a = s.substring(6);
        Log.e("after trim is?", a);
        x.remove(i);
        x.add(i, a);
    }
    // check if the element got added back
    Log.e("Trimmer function", x.get(1));

    return x;
}
```

This will help you hopefully!